# How can I add a working iframe in a phonegap android app?

Tags: html, cordova

I have a phonegap project and I have /assets/www/index.html. In the index.html file, I have an iframe. I preview the app and the iframe works but when I export the app as an apk the iframe is blank. Can anyone help me or tell me why this happens ? Thanks

Comment: What are you using the `iframe` for? Do you really need it? Maybe it can be done in another way. `iframe` can be very tricky in mobile apps and different platforms.

Comment: Ok, I want to use the iframe because in the app will be tabs, one with blog, one with website, and one with tweets. In each one, I will add an iframe to the blog, website, and the tweets !

Comment: You can inject those pages directly in a `div` using jQuery `('selector').load('url')` method.

Comment: I'll see if it works. Thanks

Comment: Can you please give me a small code on jsfiddle ? I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframe` can be very tricky in mobile apps and different platforms. Maybe it can be done in another way? You can inject those pages directly into a div using jQuery `('selector').load('url')` method. Here is an example that loads twitter page into a `div`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyLittleBrowser" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; overflow: scroll;"></div>
<script>
  $("#MyLittleBrowser").load("https://crossorigin.me/https://www.twitter.com/");
</script>
```

Make sure you whitelist all the websites that you will be loading. With the new phonegap versions >= 5, you need the whitelist plugin which has the new syntax for that purpose. If you want to use the old syntax, you can use the legacy plugin. For example, to run my code above, you need to add this to your `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist" spec="1.1.1" />
<access origin="https://crossorigin.me" />
```

Note: I used the https://crossorigin.me service in my example because otherwise twitter would give me a CORS error because it's a different domain than SO and it doesn't allow CORS. In your project, you don't need to use this service as long as the page your loading allows CORS access. If the page is yours, remember to allow CORS by adding this header to your page:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); //PHP
Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //C#
```

Comment: It doesn't work in phonegap but here, on stackoverflow, it works perfectly!

Comment: If it works with your phonegap app, can you send me the project ?

Comment: Yes, of course it works with phonegap. I use it everywhere in my projects. Make sure you white list all the websites you are loading. See my updated answer for how to do that.

Comment: I can't make it work... Can you send me an example project with the code in it ? Because I test it on my website and the code works but in phonegap nothing works

Comment: Can you give me a demo project with the latest phonegap ? I don't have config.xml, do you think I can get a demo project from github ? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-sample-hybrid-android is this a good one ? I mean, I can download it and change the app name...

Comment: I don't like that example. You can try [this one](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world). If you use the online Phongap build service, your config.xml should be inside the www folder which is all what you need to upload (zipped) the build service. If you're compiling your project on your computer, the config.xml should be in the root folder outside the www folder [like this example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-blank/tree/master/template_src).

Comment: How can I create a build from scratch on build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: Use [the link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world) I provided above as a template to start. When you're ready to build, zip your www folder and upload it to build.phonegap.com.

Comment: Ok do I have to change the description, etc in the config.xml ?

Comment: Yes. The config.xml file has all the instructions and settings for building your project

Comment: And in the package.json ? I leave it how it is ?

Comment: For build.phonegap.com, you only need the www folder. Delete everything else.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I be right back when I finish. Do I still need to add what you told me to add? Because it's already there in config.xml...

Comment: THANK. YOU. SO. MUCH! IT WORKED! I accepted your answer. I hope that you will help other people in the same way you helped me. Another time, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't load"? The css in phonegap app is no different from the css for a standard website, so make sure the path is correct and it should work.

Comment: I mean the crossorigin

Comment: You should not use the crossorigin.me service in your project. I had to use it in my example because that's the only way in stackoverflow. In your project you must have control over the page that you want to load and you need to allow CORS as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: BTW I found that the iframe was working, it was my project which was built wrong. Thanks for giving me a good template

Comment: Yes, the `iframe` works for basic stuff, but it gets tricky to support complex features on different platforms (iOS, Android, BB, Win).

Comment: I want the app only for android ;) I want to ask you a final question... I have a header and a footer, and I want the iframe to be displayed between the header and footer, I mean the blank between them should be filled with the iframe. I did width and height 100% but it overrides the header...

Comment: Yes, you cannot use 100%. You need to subtract the height of the header and footer. You can use `calc()` css function for that. For example, if you have your header 20px and footer 15px, try something like `height: calc(100% - 35px);`.

Comment: I do not have a specific height for the header and footer. I got the template from materializecss.com and the template is starter template... I just removed the company bio in footer...

Comment: Then you can probably use flex boxes. Start a new question and put the HTML and CSS that you already have so we can help you with it.

Comment: Ok! Can you go check my projects at http://touficapks.ml ? There is Seconds, Stop smoking etc... Thanks again for your hard work with me ;)

Comment: Like I said, you need to start a new question here on SO and post your HTML and CSS in the question. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use iFrames in cordova make sure you white list the domain by adding
`<allow-navigation href="urls which you navigate to" />` to your config.xml 
and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://iframe url">
```

to your .html file where you are using iframe.

Or you can use jQuery onload for any div like Racil said

```
<div id="divid"></div>
<script>
$( "#divid" ).load( "url to load" );
</script>
```

Source
[jquery](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: no that's not possible. dont look into www directory, it will be created in the project's home directory.

Comment: I searched everywhere... I can send you a zip of the project

Comment: how did you create the cordova project.?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqp4qfhkrl39a2n/MyPhoneGapApp.zip?dl=0 Look here is a sample project similar to the one I use.

Comment: I created the phonegap project with a phonegap IDE

Comment: AIDE Phonegap on android

Comment: in that case you have to manually create a config.xml file in your res/xml folder

Comment: Please take a look at the zip I sent you... There is 3 res but they don't have xml in them...

Comment: create an xml folder and inside that create config.xml

Comment: I did, and I created the config.xml file and it is empty... What do I add in it ?

Comment: Shouldn't I add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-sample-hybrid-android/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure, I added the xml folder into the res folder which is next to the assets one.

Comment: yes .. and add <allow-navigation href="urls which you navigate to" /> in it

Comment: I get an error in config.xml error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 8.

Comment: Can you please post the screen shot of your config.xml

Comment: Why don't you try Cordova CLI instead? This will create the file for you

Comment: OK, now the error is fixed but the app crashes on launch

Comment: Okay try Cordova CLI.

Comment: I am using an android phone to do that so I can't use Cordova CLI